# Return condicional en ejecucion Secuencial para moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy realizando una prueba usando `moq`, en esta prueba el valor del campo alias es único en mi repositorio, es decir si registro aun usuario con el mismo alias debo esperar una excepción, esta es mi primer versión de la prueba.

```
 [TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.ArgumentException), "el Alias ya existe para otro usuario")]
public void Test_RegistrarUnNuevoUsuario_AliasYaRegistrado()
{
    //Arrange
    string aliasUsuario = "Jocker";
    var repositorioMock = new Mock<IUsuarioRepositorio>();
    repositorioMock.Setup(x => x.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>())).Returns(2);

    repositorioMock.SetupSequence(m => m.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(null)
                                                                                    .Returns(new Usuario { UsuarioId = 1 });

    var servicio = new UsuarioServicio(repositorioMock.Object);

    //act
    var idNuevoUsuario1 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Fulano", Alias = "Jocker"});
    var idNuevoUsuario2 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Juan", Alias = "Jocker"});

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(idNuevoUsuario2 > 0);
}
```

En el método de registrar usuario antes de crearlo, primero se valida que el alias no exista esta es la regla:

```
   //unico alias
        var usuarioBD= _repositorio.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(nuevoUsuario.Alias);

    if (usuarioBD.UsuarioId!=null)
        throw new ArgumentException("el Alias ya existe para otro usuario");
```

La prueba se ejecuta bien pero tiene una falla ,
 si a los usuarios los declaro con Alias diferentes sigue siendo una prueba valida:

```
var idNuevoUsuario1 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Fulano", Alias = "Jocker"});
var idNuevoUsuario2 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Juan", Alias = "Chapulin"});
```

Para esto estoy cambiando el método secuencial de tal forma que busco validar el alias del segundo registro:

Estoy intentando declarar algo así:

```
    string aliasUsuario1 =string.Empty;
    repositorioMock.SetupSequence(m => m.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string alias) => { aliasUsuario1 = alias; return new Usuario { UsuarioId = 0 }; })
                                                                                    .Returns( (string aliasRegistrado) => aliasRegistrado==aliasUsuario1? new Usuario { UsuarioId = 1 }
                                                                                                                                                         : null;
```

Esto me da un error de compilación:

> "cannot convert lamda expression to type 'Usuario' because is not a
>   delegate type".

Como podría hacer esta comparación para condicionar el valor de Retorno?

Comment: el metodo `ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias()` que tipo de objeto retorna ? no es una instancia de `Usuario`

Comment: Retorna un tipo usuario  si existe en la base de datos  regresa con la info de usuario ObternerUsuarioPorAlias tambien se usa para otro metodo de busqueda de usuarios, reutilizo ese metodo y si usuario existe el id debe ser >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo con la documentacion esta es la respuesta:

En la ejecucion del primer registro, usando  Callback se guarda el alias del primer usuario y en returns se agrega un parametro para comparar con el primer registro:

```
 [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(System.ArgumentException), "el Alias ya existe para otro usuario")]
        public void Test_RegistrarUnNuevoUsuario_AliasYaRegistrado()
        {
            //Arrange
            string aliasUsuarioRegistrado = string.Empty;
            var repositorioMock = new Mock<IUsuarioRepositorio>();
            repositorioMock.Setup(x => x.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>()))
                               .Callback((Usuario usuario1)=> aliasUsuarioRegistrado=usuario1.Alias)
                               .Returns(2);


            repositorioMock.Setup(m => m.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(It.IsAny<string>()))
                     .Returns((string alias) => alias == aliasUsuarioRegistrado ? new Usuario { Alias = alias, UsuarioId = 4 }
                                                                               : null;      

            var servicio = new UsuarioServicio(repositorioMock.Object);

            //act
            var idNuevoUsuario1 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Fulano", Alias = "Jocker"});
            var idNuevoUsuario2 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Juan", Alias = "Jocker"});


            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(idNuevoUsuario2 > 0);
        }
```

Asi que cuando los alias no son los mismos la prueba no devuelve la excepcion y si cuando registro dos alias iguales, de esta manera la prueba es correcta.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que estas equivocando es la lógica de tu negocio, esta mal implementada.

Si estas recuperando un usuario en base a su `alias` que es `único` no se valida el id de esa entidad, sino que obtengas una instancia

```
 var usuarioBD = _repositorio.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(nuevoUsuario.Alias);

 if (usuarioBD != null)
     throw new ArgumentException("el Alias ya existe para otro usuario");
```

Se supone que `ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias()` debe retornar `null` si es que no existe ningún usuario con ese alias

Para hacer que falle solo defines

```
repositorioMock.SetupSequence(m => m.ObtenerUsuarioPorAlias(It.IsAny<string>()))
                                         .Returns(null)
                                         .Returns(new Usuario { UsuarioId = 1 });
```

Al devolver `null` al primera vez ese usuario pasar correctamente, el segundo al ser encontrado fallara

Comment: asi es, una declaracion parecida fue mi primer intento porque para alias diferentes de usuarios diferentes me seguira entregando una excepcion , var idNuevoUsuario1 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Fulano", Alias = "Jocker"});
var idNuevoUsuario2 = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(new Usuario() { Nombre = "Juan", Alias = "Chapulin"}); Por eso mi duda de agregar un condicionante en Return en la ejecucion secuencial

Comment: no va ningun condicionate en el `Returns`